# Problems with var page = $(this).attr("id");

Tags: scripting

i have been working for hours on the live search concept, and i am having problems with just one part of the Code.

#### html

```
<input id="searchs" autocomplete="off" /> 
<div class="livesearch" ></div>
```

#### javascript

```
 $(function () {
        $("#searchs").keyup(function () {
           var searchs = $(this).val();
           $.get("livesearch.php?searchs=" + searchs, function (data) {
              if (searchs) {
                 $(".livesearch").html(data);
              } else {
                 $(".livesearch").html("");
              }
           });
        });
        $(".page").live("click", function () {
           var searchs = $("#searchs").val();

           var page = $(this).attr("id");

           $(".livesearch").load("livesearch.php?searchs=" + searchs + "&page=" +page);
        });
     });
```

the part `var page = $(this).attr("id");` is not working. The page shows the error below

```
Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xamp\...
```

and this error comes from the `livesearch.php` file which intends to use the index.

I am new to this way of scripting.

what could be the problem?

the part where the error is coming from on livesearch.php

```
if($_GET["page"]){
$pagenum = $_GET["page"];
} else {
$pagenum = 1;
}
```

Comment: also post code of `livesearch.php`

Comment: replace `if($_GET["page"]){` with `if(isset($_GET["page"]) && $_GET["page"]){`. This will check if the `page` index exists before trying to evaluate it.

Comment: woow, and it worked, 
so does this mean the index "page" wasnt really necessary ?

Comment: that you should know :) absence of it doesn't break _your logic_ by making `$pagenum = 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".livesearch").load("livesearch.php", {
    searchs: searchs,
    page: page
});
```

You weren't properly encoding the search string, and it could cause problems parsing the URL. jQuery will do that for you if you put the parameters in an object.

Comment: Read the comments above, add some thoughts to your answer and you might see your answer accepted (hopefully **☻**)

Comment: @roXon With my change, the `$_GET` variables should always be set, so the `isset()` check shouldn't make a difference. They're still a good idea, but not related to the original problem.